# Convert Data table into string using string builder

Tags: c#, string

I have a table full of data, I would like to know how i would be able to convert each of the rows in this data Table into a string using String builder. all i want to see on the string is the page name and the status.

```
|ID | PagenName |  error | Message | Status |
|1  | a         |  1     | tt      | failed |
|2  | a         |  1     | tt      | success|
|3  | a         |  1     | tt      | success|
|4  | a         |  1     | tt      | success|
```

Comment: Where is your source code? Can you paste?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq-To-DataSet to select what you need:

```
var data = From row in table
           Let PagenName = row.Field(Of String)("PagenName")
           Let Status = row.Field(Of String)("Status")
           Select String.Format("PageName: {0} Status: {1}", PagenName, Status)
```

If you want a single string, for example separated by `Environment.NewLine`:

```
Dim result As String = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, data)
Console.Write(result)
```

I would prefer such code because it's readable.